# JBOSS/WildFly: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32-program, how am I supposed to fix this?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to launch WildFly via IntelliJ
When I add the following line inside the Startup Script:

```
..\bin\standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error running 'JBOSS':
Cannot run program "C:...." (in directory "C...": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32-program
```

I've read on StackOverFlow that this might be a mismatch between 32 bit and 64 bit DLL files? But I doubt this is the case. It works fine without that tag, but I need to launch my server with this startup script.

Or am I missing something else when trying to run a .jar file? I have javac, JAVA_HOME and java -version setup, am I missing something else?

Comment: I see no reason for anyone to run a 32 bit JVM.  Make sure you've got a 64 bit JVM.

Comment: That seems very fair yes. I had no idea it was doing this. Been stuck for hours.. 
Is this inside the project, or IntelliJ, or a config on my Java install?
EDIT:
JVM says it's 64 bit inside my CMD Prompt.. So it can't be that can it?

Comment: Uninstall the JDK you have and try again. Make sure you give IntelliJ the path to you installation. Which version of JBOSS?  Make sure you use the JDK for which it’s certified. Probably JDK 8.

Comment: I have JDK 8 yes? And it compiles and works fine?
JBoss is JBoss 17.0.1 Final, but WildFly of course?

Comment: "WildFly 17 also is heavily tested and runs well on Java 8. We plan to continue to support Java 8 at least through WildFly 18, and probably beyond." - JDK 8 or higher.

Comment: You are sure it's about the JDK? Cause it says "Cannot run program "C:\....\...\..\wildfly-17.0.1.Final\bin\standalone.sh" (in directory "C:\....\...\..\wildfly-17.0.1.Final\bin"):..." 

I didn't specify so clearly maybe, only wrote C.. Still about the JDK? JBoss can't be set to 32 bit or something like that?

Comment: How silly of me. .sh is a Unix script. .bat is what you need to run on Windows.  Which operating system does your computer have?

Comment: Windows 10.. I haven't heard of this but changing to .bat now and I got a new error. "Could not locate "C:\Users\jonat\Documents\Java Projects\realsurvey\WildF\wildfly-17.0.1.Final\bin\jboss-modules.jar".
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script."

Atleast some progress. Also, I reinstalled the JDK and JRE before trying .bat, didn't work either.

Comment: No. You can’t fix this by renaming the file. .sh is a Bash script; you need a windows script. Should be one in the /bin folder.

Comment: It started though via IntelliJ, as a .sh, when I didn't alter with the full xml settings at the end of it. Now however, it won't start at all. IntelliJ keeps looking in the wrong path to find JBOSS, even though my windows finds it perfectly fine..

Comment: Give IntelliJ the right path. You told it where to look when you added JBoss

Comment: You also have a way to see precisely what script IntelliJ is using to launch the app.  Change it to the correct thing if it's available.  If it's not you have another issue.  I'm running on Mac.  I see standalone.bat and standalone.sh in my local /bin folder.  You should, too.

Comment: This was so interesting let me tell you that.. I was doing the right thing all along, except for the .sh script then I guess. 
But I learnt something from you with the script, thank you! It was very useful actually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own post because my situation was a really special one, but none the less it would have helped me if I began at this point.

My first issue was that I had no idea I was supposed to use the bat script. (I bet this will give some laughs but whatever)

The second issue, which made everything so confusing, was that my JBOSS_HOME environment variable wasn't setup right.. Well what do you mean wasn't setup right, that's easy bro? Well yes of course it is - but IntelliJ didn't register it properly. So whenever I configured everything, it kept saying that it looked toward another directory, and might not work properly within JBOSS's console.

My fix:
Path was setup correct, but under IntelliJ IDEA's values, it said %JBOSS_HOME%\bin. I wasn't sure if it pointed to the same JBOSS setup that Windows does, or if it pointed to one I had deleted. I removed this from IntelliJ IDEA's path (NOT the Path within Windows) and now IntelliJ finds my JBOSS correctly and it works..

Maybe this helps someone in the future. It would have saved me some time, but atleast I learnt something.

Comment: I don’t use environment variables. IntelliJ should be given the full absolute path to JBOSS.

Comment: This could also be done yes, perhaps if I remove the variable now it will work regardless. IntelliJ kept looking for an old WildFly I had, that I replaced with a new one at a different location. But my "echo %JBOSS_HOME%" kept pointing to the right one in CMD prompt, but not within IntelliJs console..

Comment: You should not be using JBOSS_HOME.  I'm telling you that it's not necessary or desirable.

Comment: Answered your own post?  I think I had something to do with it.

Comment: You did and I am thankful, I just wanted to add the weird part of how I actually thought I had the right variable but still didn't. In case someone else gets stuck.. :) didn't mean to steal the spotlight mate. Thanks again!